# How to edit the UI of woocommerce checkoutpage in woocommerce.

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, woothemes

I'm trying to edit the checkout page of woocommerce. the place where it says in this link, new user/registered user. Instead of the text i would like to have button placed to perform the same action. I'm a noob and trying to develop something on my own and learn. Its a woocommerce platform and have created the child theme as well. Any help with the answers, code and suggestions will be much appreciated.

http://www.chocozonia.com/checkout/

Answer (score 0):

user3079582 since you say you are only just beginning to learn WooCommerce, StackOverflow is not the best place to start. You'll find much more useful material for beginners in [Woo Docs](http://docs.woothemes.com)

About your question, I don't see `new user/registered user` anywhere on the page that you gave the link for. In any case, if you are interested to change any part of a WooCommerce page, you should look at the [WooCommerce Template Structure Documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: Its under the checkout option.

Comment: Just add any product to cart, and then checkout. There will be a option saying register as a user, If you notice that button it will be something like a text on which clicking you will notice a dropdown which asks you to register, I want the text to be replaced by a button.

Comment: user3079582 as I wrote, there is a very detailed explanation about WooCommerce's templating system in the pages I gave you the links for. Please have a look there.